# convert a list of objects to a nested map in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have a list of objects as follows:

```
Rating {
Long id;
String aRating;
String bRating;
Date date;

//getters and Setters
}

List<Rating> list = //list with some values in it.
```

I have to convert the above list to a nested map:

```
Map<Date, Map<CustomEnum, String>> 


Enum CustomEnum {

     aRatingEnum("aRating", "someValue");
     bRatingEnum("bRating", "someValue");

   }
```

suppose List contains following values:

```
Id, Date, aRating, bRating
1 , 2/2/2019, A+, B+
2, 2/2/2018, A, B
```

then this needs to be converted to following map:

```
Map = {2/2/2019={aRatingEnum=A+, bRatingEnum=B+}, 2/2/2018 = {aRatingEnum=A, bRatingEnum=B}}
```

I have tried using java 8:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x->x.getDate(), Collectors.toMap(
//here I am not able to proceed further how should I approach please help.
)))
```

Comment: Enum is for the understainding purpose,the code is not copied,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toMap` collects several items into a single collection. What you have is a single object (`Rating`) and want to create a `Map` out of it.

I think what you want is `collectingAndThen` which allows you to group by date and then do the transfer to the `Map` in the finishing `Function`.

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(x->x.getDate(), 
                        lr -> {
                            Map<CustomEnum, String> result = new EnumMap<>();
                            Rating r = lr.get(0); // take first rating for that date
                            result.put(CustomEnum.aRatingEnum, r.getARating());
                            result.put(CustomEnum.bRatingEnum, r.getBRating());
                            return result;
                        })));
```

Or refactor that lambda into a method, or use `Map.of` if you're using Java 9 or higher.

This will give you a `Map<Date, Map<CustomEnum, String>>`.

Comment: but I want only nested Map not list, could it not be possible? moreover thanks for your reponse.

Comment: @ghufranne The list is created because you might have more than one `Rating` per date. You'll have to decide how to handle several ratings.

Comment: @ghufranne not in the object, but you may have several objects for the same date in the list you're streaming. But I made a mistake anyway, I'll edit to let the finisher only use the first object.

Comment: lr.get(0); is wrong, lr would be a map of list, the result of grouping by..